# How to match custom template to schema in Meteor AutoForm?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

In this minimal example I have two schemas, one for a `Person` and another called `Groups` that defines a collection.  Using AutoForm, I want to apply a custom template to any occurrence of `PersonSchema`, regardless of the parent schema.

```
SimpleSchema.PersonSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    optional: false,
    label: "First Name"
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    optional: false,
    label: "Last Name"
  }
});

Groups = new Mongo.Collection('groups');

Groups.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        optional: false,
        label: "Group Name"
    },
    people: {
        type: [SimpleSchema.PersonSchema],
        minCount: 1
    }
}));
```

I understand that I can attach a template to the AutoForm via the template attribute as well as some additional classes like so:

```
{{> quickForm id="addGroupForm" collection="Groups" type="insert" template="bootstrap3-horizontal" label-class="col-sm-3" input-col-class="col-sm-9"}}
```

How can I create a template for just the `Person` section of the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Meteor AutoForm documentation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#theme-templates), `bootstrap3-horizontal` can be used with `afFormGroup`, `afQuickField` or `quickForm` only. So, if you want to use `template="bootstrap3-horizontal"` just for the `PersonSchema` section in your form, you will need to set the `template` attribute for the appropriate `afQuickField`.

For example:

```
{{#autoForm id="addGroupForm" collection="Groups" type="insert"}}
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add a Group</legend>
        {{> afQuickField name='name'}}
        {{> afQuickField name='people' template="bootstrap3-horizontal" label-class="col-sm-3" input-col-class="col-sm-9"}}
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Insert</button>
{{/autoForm}}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the approach I ended up settling on, I appreciate the clarification... helps with the sanity :)